# AJAX is Returning the HTML of the Requesting Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

*Social Networking Site:* Posts are displayed on the home page. They can be liked and commented on. If a post is liked, it updates the like table through AJAX and have like count incremented by one. This works fine in `home.php` but not on `user.php` which is the user profile page. AJAX is returning the entire page (of the requesting page, `user.php`) if I click on `like` button, with some errors that its PHP variables are undefined. The URL is actually like this `http://localhost/mysite/user.php?userID=yax` but it is redirected and rewritten by `.htaccess` as `http://localhost/mysite/user/yax`. I guess it is the one causing the problem because the same AJAX is working fine in `home.php`. The `likes.php` file updates the **LIKE TABLE** and returns the incremented value and have it appended to the like button. This works just fine in the `home.php`.

**AJAX code:**

```
$(".mlike").click(function () {
    $(".murconform").submit(function(e){
        return false;
    });
    var $this=$(this);
    var post_id = $(this).val();
    var user_id = $(".user_id").text();
    alert('Post: '+post_id +' User: '+user_id);
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "likes.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: { post : post_id , user : user_id },
      dataType: "html"
    });
    request.done(function( msg ) {    
        $this.prev('.likecount').html( msg ); 
    });
});
```

**.htaccess code:**

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase /mysite/user/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /user\.php\?user=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Any help will be appropriately appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you shouldn't use relative url's in your `$.ajax` request. Try something like this: `url: "localhost/likes.php"`

Comment: @andreivictor: Thanks but that doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: your htaccess is causing a 302 redirect on that filename. Try commenting out lines 4 and 5. Or can you just create another file to handle the ajax? like `user_likes.php` or something.

Comment: @Pjack: After commenting out `RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]` and I refreshed the page. It says page not found. And when I commented line 5, nothing happened. The problem still remains.